# SimpleTimeLimiter shutdown

Tags: guava

I am using `com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter`,
wondering if this takes care of threadpool shutdown ? I am constructing this using noargs constructor  `new SimpleTimeLimiter()` , but this does not provide a way to call `shutdown()`.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the JavaDoc of [ExecutorService.shutdown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29)

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but **no new tasks will be accepted**. Invocation has no
>   additional effect if already shut down.

The backing `ExecutorService.submit(callable)` will be called ONCE inside of `SimpleTimeLimiter`. Since NO other new tasks will be submitted any more, so `shutdown()` is not needed.

But if we use constructor `SimpleTimeLimiter(ExecutorService executor)`, then we have to be responsible for `shutdown()`.